# Backwards autocomplete in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

E.g. if I have files abc.txt, def.txt in my directory I can type

```
a[Tab]
```

and it autocompletes to abc.txt.
Is there some shortcut I can use do the reverse? E.g. I type

```
f.txt[KeyCombo]
```

and it autocompletes to def.txt?
If such a shortcut doesn't exist, is there a .bashrc script someone has written to do this?

Comment: Some people recommend [fuzzy_bash_completion](https://github.com/mgalgs/fuzzy_bash_completion). And you can write your own auto-completion rules.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard key combinations in shells are usually pre-defined to execute some form of function,instead of being given to option to be used as shortcut keys for a for opening a file in the **shell**.

example

CTRL-t : Clear the screen.
ALT+t OR ESC+t: Transpose words

CTRL-u : Deletes entire line.

CTRL-k : Deletes to end of line from current cursor position.

HOME OR CTRL-a : Moves cursor to beginning of line.
...etc...

Nevertheless, it is possible to assigned filenames to variables in your bash.rc  file and then  calling these variables when needed (I would advise this for long filenames since autocomplete in the shell works is very efficient)